# Error sending string message to Handler : cannot convert String to int

Tags: java, android

From the main thread of my app, I am trying to send string messages, which are to be sent to TCPClient will will continously send over the socket.

This is my TCPClient :

```
public class TCPClient extends Thread
{
    String ip;
    int port;
    PrintWriter out;
    Handler handler;

    TCPClient(String ip, int port)
    {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;

        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip,port);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("OKLINUX","Exception while creating socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        handler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                Log.d("OKLINUX","Data sent : "+msg.arg1);
                out.println(msg.arg1);
                out.flush();
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

On my main thread :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sender = new TCPClient("192.168.0.7",2016);
        sender.start();

        //some other code

       Message msg = Message.obtain();
       msg.arg1 = "some string";   //this line gives error
       sender.handler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

How can I pass the string?

Comment: Where do you want to pass a string ?

Comment: `public int arg1; ` is line from source code of Message. `arg1` and `arg2` are lower-cost alternatives to using setData() if you only need to store a few integer values . that means, you can store integer only, not string in that variable arg1.

Answer (score 0):

Because arg1 and arg2 is int values for passing request type. Use arg.obj instead

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadoc `arg1` is an `int` not a `String` that is why you get this exception.

More details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#arg1)

> arg1 and arg2 are lower-cost alternatives to using setData() if you
>   only need to store a few integer values.

Still from the javadoc, you should try to use `obj` instead

> An arbitrary object to send to the recipient. When using Messenger to
>   send the message across processes this can only be non-null if it
>   contains a Parcelable of a framework class (not one implemented by the
>   application). For other data transfer use setData(Bundle).